# ubuntu 14.04 doesn't start normaly

Tags: boot, 14.04

after installing new version of ubuntu. that doesn't start normaly. i must be start that with recovery mode and choose resume to start successfull ubuntu . in start normaly sceen is black and doesn't any change

Comment: Have you tried anything?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going into recovery mode and running "sudo update-grub" and that may resolve the conflicts where it seems to be not getting past grub. Other than that you might try opening up a normal session from the method mentioned in the question and using grub customizer to try and find any problems by reinstalling with that.